# Line Integral in second quadrant of Unit Circle

Tags: line-integrals, greens-theorem

If I am asked to compute

$$\int_c F . dr$$

Where

$$F(x,y) = <d/dx f(x, y), d/dy f(x,y)>$$
    and
$$f(x,y) =\sin(x^3 + y^3)$$

and C is the portion of the unit circle in the second quadrant, oriented counterclockwise, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: What is $F(x,y)$ ?

Comment: I had trouble using MathJax.
F(x, y) equals the partial derivatives with respect to x and y (in vector form) of the function sin(x^3 + y^3)

Comment: Can you use Green theorem?

Comment: Technically not because Green's theorem, as far as I know, would be used for enclosed structures, not simple lines.

Comment: So do straightforward

Comment: what is $dr$ here? Maybe $dr=(dx,dy)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=(\cos t,\sin t)$ with $t\in[\dfrac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ be the parametrization of $C$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_C F.dr
&= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\left(3\cos^2t\cos(\cos^3t+\sin^3t),3\sin^2t\cos(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)\right)(-\sin t,\cos t)\ dt \\
&= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\left(-3\cos^2t\sin t+3\sin^2t\cos t\right)\cos(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)\ dt \\
&= \sin(\cos^3t+\sin^3t)\Big|_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \\
&= \color{blue}{-2\sin1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You need the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem):
$$\int_\gamma (\nabla f) \cdot d\mathbf r =
f(\mathbf r_2) - f(\mathbf r_1) =
f(-1, 0) - f(0, 1) =
-2 \sin 1.$$